# How do I change color of selected issue in GreenHopper planning board?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

Default color for a selected issue on planning board is so light that I have to stress my eyes to be able to see which issue is selected at present on planning board.

Comment: I created https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/GHS-9687 to request that color not be used as the sole indicator of this information. If you want to be able to change the color of the selected issue I suggest commenting there

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the color in agile board configuration. Check the following link to see more details on how to do this https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/Configuring+Card+Colours

Comment: This won't let you configure the color for the currently selected card. It lets you configure only the card colors by JQL patterns, which is a nice feature, but not what the requestor is looking for.